# How to manage passwords within a group of people

Tags: architecture, passwords, password-protection

We would like to build a framework which allows us to protect passwords and let it be shared or used only within a group. Users within our company would need access to different passwords of various subsystems.

e.g. There are several projects (ProjectA, ProjectB ..)
Each project provides access to several sub systems (say twilio, bitly, aws ..)
Group of people within a Project will have access to these and not others within a company

Is there a library or product which already supports this ..or how should this be built

Comment: Probably, you may want to make some proxy to all of those systems? So proxy authenticates and authorizes a user, and then acts on behalf of authorized user, but never discloses password to him.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding you but this is generally a bad idea since, while it still provides authorisation, authentication is partially 'broken' - there is no way to identify a specific person.

The normal approach would be to authenticate each user individually but to assign them to roles/groups, and those roles would be your unit of authorisation.